# Strong parameters are not cominng from view to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm sending the parameters from view and to get the strong parameters in controller.

I am trying this on ruby version ruby 2.3.1

In view --

```html
<%= form_tag cardamoms_create_auction_path,:enctype =>"multipart/form-data" do %> 
    <div class="field">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= label_tag :company %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= select_tag :company_id,options_for_select(@companies.collect{|c|[c.name,c.id]}),prompt:"Select company",class:"form-control",required: true%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= label_tag "" %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= label_tag :auction_number %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=text_field_tag :auction_number,"",class: 'form-control',required: true,placeholder: "Ex. 19" %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= label_tag "" %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= label_tag "auction_date" %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=text_field_tag :auction_date,"", "data-provide" => 'datepicker', class: "datepicker form-control",id: 'selectDate1',placeholder: "Auction date(yyyy-mm-dd)" ,required: true%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= label_tag "image_upload" %>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= label_tag "start_date" %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=text_field_tag :start_date,"", "data-provide" => 'datepicker', class: "datepicker form-control",id: 'selectDate2',placeholder: "Start date(yyyy-mm-dd)"%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= label_tag "" %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= label_tag "end_date" %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%=text_field_tag :end_date,"", "data-provide" => 'datepicker', class: "datepicker form-control",id: 'selectDate3',placeholder: "End date(yyyy-mm-dd)"%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= submit_tag "Submit",class:"btn btn-success" ,remote: true%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

In controller -

```rb
private

def auction_params
  params.permit(:company_id,:auction_number,:auction_date,:start_date,:end_date)
end
```

I am expecting in controller -

```rb
private

def auction_params
  params.require(:auction).permit(:company_id,:auction_number,:auction_date,:start_date,:end_date)
end
```

How do I change the view in such a way that the incoming parameters are in the format `params[:auction][:company_id]` instead of `params[:company_id]`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to set in the view file such that data comes in controller will come like params[:auction][:company_id] but right now it is coming like params[:company_id]

Comment: I recommend taking a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects

Comment: In form_tag how should I create action params[:auction] will be a hash with keys :auction_number and :company_id.

Comment: For model forms use [`form_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) or [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) (using the `:model` option) instead of [`form_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag).

Comment: I currently don't have the time to write a full answer, if this isn't solved this evening I'll add one.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I change the view in such a way that the incoming parameters
>   are in the format params[:auction][:company_id] instead of
>   params[:company_id]?

As [`3limin4t0r`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55397636/strong-parameters-are-not-cominng-from-view-to-controller-in-rails#comment97520252_55397636) suggested you can use [`form_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) or [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)

Or you can set it explicitly so:

```
<%= select_tag :company_id,...
```

becomes

```
<%= select_tag "auction[company_id]",...
```

Same goes for other tags

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [form_for @object](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) to achieve this. As the wiki docs say, `form_for` Creates a form that allows the user to create or update the attributes of a specific model object. 
Something like:

```
<%= form_for(@post, url: super_posts_path) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

should do the trick.